# Using IIS7 Logs to determine how many users have JavaScript disabled?

Tags: iis-7, logging, javascript

I know that I can get OS and\or browser settings types from the IIS logs, but is there a way to also see if a user has JavaScript disabled? I am looking for a to determine how many of our users are not running JavaScript.

Thanks,
ZK

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As this was a secured site and also had a limited number of users, I ended up just saving this info in a user table on the data base.

I set a variable "JSEnabled" to false, and using JavaScript set it to true on log in.

Answer (score 1):

The IIS logs won't keep that information, but you can use a solution like Google Analytics which is able to obtain that information and more.  It's free and great for finding out client-side information like that.

Comment: I guess I could use Google Analytics to get a count of visitors with JavaScript enabled (as the free version requires a JavaScript file to run), and then use the IIS logs to get the full list of visitors and subtract the GA number. I was hoping for a better more automated solution.

Comment: The problem is that the Javascript info isn't included in the HTTP Headers, so it's not available to IIS when it logs the data. It will require some sort of javascript on the page itself to determine weather or not it's supported. You could write your own js add-on and have it make a call to another logging page on your server and append the information in the querystring. That will be similar to Google Analytics but allow you to use your own IIS logs to collect the data. Google Analytics is probably easier.

Answer (score 1):

A half useful method would be to write two cookies, one in a page header and another with Javascript, if they both are sent back to the server then JS is enabled, if neither exists then cookies are disabled.

I'm guessing that IIS is like Apache in as much that it can log cookies.